# Syntax Highlighting Gtk.Entry on Python

Tags: python, gtk, syntax-highlighting, pygtk, gtkentry

I want to highlight the text of a [Gtk.Entry](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Entry.html), like this:

[image: Example]

The first solution that came to me was foreign drawing, but I would have to manage everything myself. Other thought I had was to extend Gtk.Entry and override just the drawing of the text, but I don't think that's possible in Python.

How can I do that and take advantage of the work Gtk already does managing focus, drawing, animation, scrolling, cursor, etc.?

Comment: Show us some code

Comment: Did you consider to use a Gtk.TextView instead?

Comment: Have you checked out this?: https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#GtkSource-4

Comment: I can not use TextView or SourceView, it needs to be single-line, that is why I want to extend Entry.

Comment: Overiding the drawing of the text is definitely possible in Python. Show us some code.